# Till when is a CRUD repository lock held when using the @Lock annotation?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, crud

When I mention `@Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` for a CRUD transaction, till when is the lock held(when it is for a read operation)?

I read in https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking that :

> They all are retained until the transaction commits or rolls back.

What happens if the `@Lock` annotation is used for a read CRUD method (like `findAll`... or similar). Is it till the scope of the variable holding the return value exists?

Comment: The answer is in the question: They all are retained until the transaction commits or rolls back. So no, it's not "till the scope of the variable holding the return value exists". It's until the transaction commits or rolls back.

Comment: @JBNizet, yes I understand that is the case when it is for a write operation. But what happens for a read operation? That was my question..

Comment: You specify which lock you want when reading data. Not when writing it. And they *all* are retained until the transaction commits or rolls back.

Comment: @JBNizet ok.. if that is the case, what happens if I dont write anything at all, I just read it for getting data, not to change and commit..

Comment: The lock will be retained until the transaction commits or rolls back. Let's say you book a flat for your holiday, and you book it until the end of July. Whether or not you actually go live in the flat doesn't matter: it's locked: no one else can go live in it. Same here.

Comment: Does that mean, if I dont write anything, and just continue, it is considered a roll back? when it actually is not a "roll back".

Comment: OK. The problem seems to be that you don't understand what a transaction is. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: @JBNizet did you mean, all the (at)Lock annotations should be used for the read methods only? And never for the write methods? Is there an article I can read that guides me on how to use (at)Lock annotations properly?

Comment: Start by reading the article you're talking about in your question. When is a lock being used?